# ffmpeg: nvidia gpu performance sub-optimal

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia

the problem seems fairly basic : i'd like to create thumbnails from incoming video in the shortest time possible, and i'm trying to do this by offloading processing to an nvidia gpu.

while i run ffmpeg, i'm monitoring the gpu usage with the nvidia-smi utility. gpu usage never goes above 15% and the amount of time to encode the thumbnails *with* gpu is only 10% less than the time required *without* the gpu. these performance levels are very disappointing.

**my question :** am i going about this the wrong way (and if so, how should i go about it), or is this gpu performance 'normal'/'reasonable' ?

SYSTEM INFORMATION

the machine is a desktop pc running windows 10, 8gb ram, intel i7-7700. the gpu is an nvidia quadro pro 4000 with cuda 11.4 installed. ffmpeg is version N-101372-gb5cb8c8767-g2fc309e699+4 (2021) running under mingw, with `--enable-cuda --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libnpp --enable-nvdec` and `--enable-nvenc`.

a typical ffmpeg command line i've used is :

```
 1 ffmpeg -hide_banner \
 2     -init_hw_device cuda=cuda:0 -filter_hw_device cuda \
 3     -hwaccel_output_format cuda \
 4     -i "$infile" \
 5     -vf "hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=w=200:h=150:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,fps=1/1,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" \
 6     -y "$outdir/%08d.png"
```

i've varied the above by supplementing some cuda-related parameters according to posts i've read here on stackoverflow and on the [nvidia transcoding guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide), but haven't been able to improve performance. adding any of `-hwaccel cuda, -hwaccel cuvid, -hwaccel nvenc` at the beginning of line 3 results in the error :
`Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'`

any pointers appreciated.